# Option Menu won't display

Tags: java, android, menu, android-actionbar

i want to show my menu with action bar, but my menu won't display, this is my source code :

```
public class EpolicyMainActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //hide title bar
    BasicDisplaySettings.toggleTaskBar(EpolicyMainActivity.this, false);
    //show status bar
    BasicDisplaySettings.toggleStatusBar(EpolicyMainActivity.this, true);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, LoginActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Login").setIndicator("",
              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.epolicy_menu_xml_home))
              .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, NABActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("NAB").setIndicator("",
              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.epolicy_menu_xml_nab))
              .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ContactActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Contact").setIndicator("",
              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.epolicy_menu_xml_contact))
              .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AgenActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Agen").setIndicator("",
              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.epolicy_menu_xml_agen))
              .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++){
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i).setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    }
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_bantuan:     
                Intent itAbout = new Intent(EpolicyMainActivity.this, EpolicyBantuan.class);
                itAbout.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(itAbout);

                break;
            case R.id.menu_exit:     
                dialogExit();

                break;
            case R.id.menu_logout:
                dialogSignOut();

                break;
        }


        return true;
    }
 public void dialogSignOut()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Apakah anda ingin sign-out?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       Intent itSignOut = new Intent(EpolicyMainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                       itSignOut.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                       startActivity(itSignOut);
                       finish();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
 public void dialogExit()
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Apakah anda ingin keluar?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       Intent itSplashEnd = new Intent(EpolicyMainActivity.this, SplashOutActivity.class);

                       itSplashEnd.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                       itSplashEnd.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                       startActivity(itSplashEnd);
                       finish();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        dialogExit();
    }
```

this is my menu.xml :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_bantuan"
    android:title="@string/menu_bantuan"
    android:orderInCategory="100" 
     android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_exit"
    android:title="@string/menu_exit"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
    android:title="@string/menu_logout"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

in my main layout, i'm using header, is this giving effect to my menu, so my menu won't display or anything else?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace in logs?

Comment: Have you tried not sending `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)`, but rather just true in `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Comment: yes, i have, but the menu still won't display

Answer (score 0):

I was under the assumption that you should always first call super.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

I am assuming your menu.xml has an appropriate menu closing tag. Do you have this xml file stored in your res/menu folder? Can you verify that onCreateOptionsMenu is called?

On Android 2.3 and lower you will have to press the menu button, whereas in later distributions it should be displayed in the title bar. Since you are using a TabActivity I assume you are writing an app for Android 2.3.

This question might be useful for the onMenuItemSelected() method:
[Merge TabActivity menu with contained Activities menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082540/merge-tabactivity-menu-with-contained-activities-menus)

For Activities within you TabActivity: [How to create an optionsMenu in an Android's TabActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102662/how-to-create-an-optionsmenu-in-an-androids-tabactivity)

Perhaps when you press the menu button, the options menu of the specific tab activity that you are in (e.g. LogInActivity) is called, and not that of its parent. Try putting this code in every subactivity:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    return getParent().onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: i have tried this code before, but my option menu still won't display

Comment: Do you have your menu.xml in the res/menu folder?

Comment: is onCreateOptionsMenu called?

Comment: I mean, are you sure that onCreateOptionsMenu() is actually called by the TabActivity everytime you press the menu button?

Answer (score 0):

Google decided to avoid using menu at all. Please read this article http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

If device doesn't have hardware menu button and you set targetSDK version > 10 user does not have ability to use menu. As short term solution you can set targetSDK = 10 as long term solution consider using ActionBar http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html